# how to add validation in xsd for blank spaces

Tags: java, xsd, saxparser

i have created basic xsd successfully however I want to add restriction for the element that it should be present and contains atleast one character. it also has 4 attributes. i am facing problem in adding restriction since I can not use simple type as the element has attributes.

Please suggest something

thanks in advance

**Added XSD data posted by OP in comments (sic)**

```
<xs:element name="Engines">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Engine" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Count" use="required" type="xs:integer" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Engine">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Model" type="Model"/>
      <xs:element ref="SerialNumber" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</element>

<xs:simpleType name="trimValueType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:minLength value="1"></xs:minLength>
    <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"></xs:whiteSpace>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:complexTyp‌​e name="Model">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="trimValueType">
      <xs:attribute name="ATTRIBUTE" use="required" />
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>


<Engines count = 1> <Engine> <Model ATTRIBUTE = "r\w"> </Model> <SerialNumber ATTRIBUTE = "r/w">1234567</SerialNumber> <Engine> <Engines>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to first create a simple type that restricts xsd:string to specify your text constraints. Then you need to define a complex type, with a simple content, which extends the simple type you just created using the attributes you want. I threw in a whitespace constraint, just to match your title, even though you're not specifically mention it in your problem statement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:simpleType name="one">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:complexType name="two">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="one">
                <xsd:attribute name="one"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="two"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="etc"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="root" type="two"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" one="anySimpleType" two="anySimpleType" etc="anySimpleType" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">root1</root>
```

Comment: i have tried this and getting exception - The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

Comment: @Shashank, what did you try, and how (as in what tool did you use)? Can you post the XML you've tried? I've just updated the post with a sample XML that validates.

Comment: I am validating the xml created with your suggestion using java SAXParser. it is validating properly if element value is blank or spaces however system is throwing exception at the end of the document like cvc-complex-type.2.2: Element 'RecordTransferFile' must have no element [children], and the value must be valid.

Comment: my xsd is 
<xs:element name="Engines"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence>
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Engine" /></xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="Count" use="required" type="xs:integer" />
</xs:complexType></xs:element><xs:element name="Engine">
<xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="Model" type="Model"/>
<xs:element ref="SerialNumber" /></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></element>

Comment: continue xsd:<xs:simpleType name="trimValueType"><xs:restriction base="xs:string"><xs:minLength value="1"></xs:minLength><xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"></xs:whiteSpace></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType><xs:complexType name="Model"><xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="trimValueType"><xs:attribute name="ATTRIBUTE" use="required" /></xs:extension></xs:simpleContent></xs:complexType>

Comment: @ShashankK it is much easier if you edited your original question to  addd the new XSD file @PetruGardea requested.  I have done so for you.  Not sure if this is a typo in your response or your real XSD file, but your element `Engine` was not closed.  you have `</element>` when you should have `</xs:element>`

Comment: @ShashankK, you're saying about an error re:RecordTransferFile yet there's no XSD fragment to show that... Can you put an XML and the error in the context of the XSD associated with your post?

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how to add xsd or xml in the question

sample xml:

<Engines count = 1>
<Engine>
<Model ATTRIBUTE = "r\w">   </Model>
<SerialNumber ATTRIBUTE = "r/w">1234567</SerialNumber>
<Engine>
<Engines>

Comment: @ShashankK you just click edit under your question and add the information.  the best way to format it is to type or paste it in then hit the `code block` option ( looks like {} )

Comment: @ShashankK, update the post with the complete XSD as well; you're missing the serialnumber element definition, etc.